# Is there a safe way to upload a malware into a centralized server?

Tags: malware, threat-mitigation

I'm facing an issue which i need to upload files to a centralized server, then relay it to other malware analysis providers (Palo Alto / etc...)

As from security perspective - it's forbidden for the file to reside in the server's file system and **memory.**

The server is ASP.NET based, and the client is C++ and i thought about streaming (currently we stream those files through IIS) - but i have some major drawbacks:

1. I think that IIS can cache data it receives, meaning - i have no control on the data flow (malware can suddenly reside in IIS memory).
2. Even if i use TCP components - who said that there's no caching in the server side? I would hate to write the entire TCP handling myself (which never will be efficient like the already written ones)
3. Other option i was thinking is to XOR the files, but if i do it on agent - compromised machine can manipulate it and send the original malware, and in server again, it could be that the malware is already cached in memory.

In addition to #3, XOR, or any password protected zip files methods (that client can send) are no acceptable aswell, as exploits might be used to decrypt this file in the server and run it (though those are slim chances).

The 3rd parties we use also expect the original file's data.

The only "acceptable" solution is to sandbox the receiving process with its files, either by a 2nd server (which is not acceptable by our on-premise customers) or in our "real" server (some kind of container - which seems like a super overkill)

Would love to hear your comments about this?

Comment: Just don't host the server yourself, then you don't have to care.

Comment: Sandboxing is just too risky (and really not needed if you encrypt the data)

Comment: we cannot encrypt the data, as we'll need to decrypt it in memory and relay it to the 3rd parties.

why Sandboxing is too risky? are you talking about a security hole that might make the machine leak to the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ZIP the file with a strong AES password or use OpenPGP or Minlock file encryption (on the client before upload).

This protects your server from accidental execution, it hides the content from scanners, it will also protect integrity and will protect the analysts from accidental exposure on/after download. In fact it's the only reliable method to avoid accidental corruption by intermediates anyway. I don't think any forensic company accepts files without packing them in containers.

Yes you stated you don't want to ZiP, but you have not mentioned convincing reason why not: The threat model 'might be decrypted and run on server' is not valid, if an attacker can generate files and execute them they don't need your encrypted content to start with.

Using streaming adds very much distribution logistic as all receivers have to know and be online at the same time. And even with streaming you want to package, encrypt and integrity protect your network transfers.

Comment: "any password protected zip files methods (that client can send) are no acceptable aswell" - as stated in the original post

Comment: @SYS_V sure but if you state impossible requirements somebody has to tell you that, right?

Comment: Given the contraints he imposes, I guess he is SOL

Comment: OpenPGP can encrypt using a destination certificate, which avoids 'passwords'.

Comment: You also have the option of TARring and compressing before OpenPGP'ing if that is enough to get around IT policies.

Comment: This is exactly what we explained to our security guys, if you get an execution rights, exploiting any zero day attack - you're already at the server and that's game over, no matter if the malware is there.
From our security guy's prespective - "might be decrypted and run on server" is valid. so my hands are tied here..

Encrypting the file in the client station can be done, but again, the decryption in our centralized server is the issue - especially when transmiting it to the 3rd parties - the malware might sit fully in memory - unencrypted...

Comment: @ArielB My sympathies.